# Rails STI and multi-level inheritance queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

In my database I have a table `people`, and I'm using single table inheritance, with these classes:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Member < Person
end

class Business < Member
end
```

[image: Demonstration of the problem]

The queries it generates confuse me.  What I want is for `Member.all` to return all Businesses as well as any other subtypes of Member. Which it does, but only if I've accessed the Business class recently. I assume it's because my classes aren't being cached in development mode (for obvious reasons), but it still seems like strange/buggy behaviour.

Is this a bug in rails? Or is it working as intended? In either case, can anyone think of a good fix for development purposes?

Comment: please specify the inheritance types in each class.

Comment: What do you mean, huan son?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is intentional behaviour—the official Rails guide on [Autoloading and Reloading Constants](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) explains it pretty well in the section on [Autoloading and STI](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-and-sti):

> …
>
> A way to ensure this works correctly regardless of the order of
>   execution is to load the leaves of the tree by hand at the bottom of
>   the file that defines the root class:
>
> ```
> # app/models/polygon.rb
> class Polygon < ApplicationRecord
> end
> require_dependency 'square'
> ```
>
> Only the leaves that are at least grandchildren need to be loaded this
>   way. Direct subclasses do not need to be preloaded. If the hierarchy
>   is deeper, intermediate classes will be autoloaded recursively from
>   the bottom because their constant will appear in the class definitions
>   as superclass.

So in your case, this would mean putting an `require_dependency "business"` at the end of your Person class.

However, beware of circular dependencies which can possibly be avoided by using `require` instead of `require_dependency` (even though it may prohibit Rails from tracking and reloading your files when changes are made—after all, `require_dependency` is a Rails-internal method).

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I'll try that next time this comes up!

Answer (score 3):

By default, Rails is not eager loading your classes in development. Try changing the following line in your `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
# Do not eager load code on boot.
config.eager_load = false
```

to:

```
# Do eager load code on boot!
config.eager_load = true
```

Comment: Nice thought! It seems to have worked in the dummy app I made to replicate the problem, but didn't fix all of my problems in my real app (which could be caused by other things). I'll mark as accepted later when I've got time to properly test. Thanks!